# PPA repositories after installing kubuntu-desktop

Tags: kubuntu, ppa

I recently installed `kubuntu-desktop` in Ubuntu 12.04.

But the problem is that I cannot get some software that I require. I think the reason is that the software repos are the originally provided Gnome Unity Repos and not the Kubuntu repos. When I do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install package-name
```

I am not able to install kdm packages because they are not found.

Whereas, I can easily find and install Gnome Unity packages.
What should I do install these softwares?

And yes, any general things-after-installing-kubuntu-desktop tips ?

**EDIT:**

Let me make myself more clear. I want to install this particular package `kdmtheme`. But when I do `apt-cache search kdmtheme` I get no results. I think the reason for this is that, when installing `kubuntu-desktop` only a few softwares and packages are installed. So what if I want to install any additional KDE software? Since no extra repos are installed while installing `kubuntu-desktop` I cannot install these via terminal using `apt-get`, can I? For doing this I will have to add additional software repos of KDE, right?
[image]

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: About what kdm packages do you speak? You're wrong with: "*I think the reason is that the software repos are the originally provided Gnome Unity Repos and not the Kubuntu repos*"

Comment: when you install kubuntu-desktop - it just installs the KDE env. on your system, so no repos are deleted, give us the screenshot of your software sources

Comment: @RaduRădeanu and @Rodislav, what @charlesX is speculating is that the repos for Kubuntu are different from Ubuntu. Is this true? Is the `sources.list` different in Kubuntu? Or are all Kubuntu-related packages included in the default Ubuntu repos?

Comment: @Alaa [I think](http://askubuntu.com/questions/320636/ppa-repositories-after-installing-kubuntu-desktop/320961#comment407689_320961) that the OP just wants to install [KDM Theme Manager](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=22120) using `apt`.

Answer (score 0):

After you install `kubuntu-desktop`, the repositories and PPAs remain unchanged. Now, I will try to explain why you cannot install what you wish. This happens most often when you give wrong names for the packages.
When you don't find a package with `apt-cache search <package_name>`, try to search for a part of the package name.

In your case, `apt-cache search kdm` will return something like:

```
jfsutils - utilities for managing the JFS filesystem
ldm - LTSP display manager
ldm-server - server components for LTSP display manager
kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins - KDE greet libraries for authentication
kdm - KDE Display Manager for X11
kdm-gdmcompat - Provide basic gdm functionality to systems running kdm
kdm-theme-aperture - very glossy Qt4/KDE4 kdm theme - aperture variant
```

**`kdm-theme-bespin - very glossy Qt4/KDE4 kdm theme`**

```
kdm-theme-tibanna - very glossy Qt4/KDE4 kdm theme - tibanna variant
libpam-usb - PAM module for authentication with removable USB block devices
lxdm - GUI login manager for LXDE
rddmarc - DMARC report processing scripts collection
```

So, the package name what were you looking for is `kdm-theme-bespin`. To install it, run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install kdm-theme-bespin
```

Comment: sorry mate, but the `kdm-theme-bespin` is a _theme_ whereas the `kdmtheme` is a theme _manager_. And these 3 themes which appear above in your answer do not appear in my terminal. They are not present in the standard repos provided by ubuntu. They appear in your case maybe because you might have added some extra ppa repo. to ur sources or which might've gotten added when you installed some software!

Comment: @charlesX There is no such a packet in the Ubuntu repositories. You can ask a new question, refering about how to install exactly what you wish. I think I answered at your problem regarding PPA repositories after installing kubuntu-desktop.

Comment: @charlesX See http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=22120. There is described how to install KDM Theme Manager and doesn't have nothing to do with Ubuntu's repositories.

Comment: yeah, that will work, but I wanted a command-line way of doing it. Or rather an `apt` way.

Comment: @charlesX There is no `apt` way since this packet doesn't exist in repositories or in any PPA.